# Can I check-in a 203 cm suitcase on a flight that starts with Japan Airlines and ends with Air France?

Tags: luggage, airlines, air-france, jal

I bought flight tickets from Air France to travel from Israel to Japan and back. On the flight back, the first leg (Tokyo Narita >> Paris CDG) is operated by Japan Airlines, then the second leg (Paris CDG >> Israel BG) is operated by Air France.

Both companies have different baggage rules. JAL allows 2 checked baggages per person, with a total linear dimension of 203 cm, while AF allows 1 checked baggage per person, with a total linear dimension of 158.

When I check my reservation details on the AF site, it simply says that I'm allowed 2 checked baggage items on the flight back, so I don't suppose the number of suitcases will be a problem. But I am worried about the dimensions - 203 cm is quite a bit larger than 158 cm. If I check in a 203 cm suitcase in Tokyo, will it cause problems when they transfer it to the AF plane?